# customizing the action bar sherlock

Tags: android

I have implemented action bar sherlock with customized style shown below

```
  <resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
  <item name= "actionBarStyle">@style/ActionStyle</item>
  <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
  <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
  </style>
  <style name= "ActionStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">#ff000000</item>
   <item name="background">#ff000000</item>
  </style>
 <style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText" >
 <item name="android:textColor">#0EBFE9</item>
 <item name = "android:showDividers">none</item>
<item name ="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name = "android:divider">#000000</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

even setting background to black the action bar shows blue divider between the action bar and navigation tab.
i have specified show dividers to none  but navigation contains divider between tab.

Answer (score 2):

You need to Inherit the Parent Theme **TabBar**, not **TabText**:

```
Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar
```

This way:

```
<style name="Theme.mActionBarTabBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
</style>
```